# Is $\int B\,\mathrm{sin}(\omega\,\mathrm{d}t)$ solvable?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Let's say I got the following integral while solving a physics problem:
>   $$ \int B\,\mathrm{sin}(\omega\,\mathrm{d}t) $$
>   where $\mathrm{d}t$ is the time differential.
>
> Is this solvable, or have I written a mathematical equivalent of BS?

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: This looks like symbol-pushing gone horribly wrong

Comment: You can also write $\int e^{dt}$ the crazy Euler version..

Comment: @Dominik Car $\int B\,\mathrm{sin}(\,\mathrm\omega t) \mathrm\, d(\omega t)$ is solvable

Answer (score 4):

To your last question, yes. I suppose a physicist might say $\sin(\omega\, dt) \approx \omega\,dt$ and then integrate. Why don't you go back a few steps to where things are mathematically meaningful and edit your post with them?

Comment: A physicist would not say $\sin(\omega\, dt) \approx \omega\,dt$. A physicist would say $\sin(\omega\, dt) = \omega\,dt$

Comment: @N.Bar LOL. Touché!

Comment: Strictly speaking, d$t^2 = 0$, so the physicist wouldn't be wrong

Comment: @Kai, no, that is far from strictly true. We're not doing wedge products of differential forms. Until we are discussing some meaningful integral, I'm not going to make any leaps.

Comment: The first thought that came to mind was the push-forward of the Lebesgue measure ${\rm d}t$ under the measurable map $t\mapsto \sin(\omega t)$, and even still...